# Python - Retrieve text from inside copied URL

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to make it so when you copy a url to your clipboard it looks inside of that link for the raw text and then copies that raw text to your clipboard automatically.

I also need it to change this link from https://pastebin.com/vwq1D1NA to https://pastebin.com/raw/vwq1D1NA before it extracts the text from inside.

For example from this pastebin link I want to automatically extract & copy the text "this is the text I want to copy to my clipboard" to my clipboard.

Copy link > Searches for text inside link > Copies text inside link to clipboard

```
import requests
import pyperclip

url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/' 

r = requests.get(url) 

content = r.text 
pyperclip.copy(content)
pyperclip.paste()
print(content)
```

Comment: Is it going to be pastebin links everytime?

Comment: pastebin & hastebin. Both work with the /raw/. Issue i'm having is just getting the URL from the user and then changing it into /raw. Links entered into code do everything I want it too.

Comment: How are you getting the url from the user?

Comment: The URl would be from the users clipboard, after they copied a link

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

If you'd like to only change the URL to the raw content URL on Pastebin when you copy it. Try this:

```
import pyperclip
from time import sleep

# get the content of clipboard
cb=pyperclip.paste()

while True:
    # get the content of clipboard while True
    current_cb = pyperclip.paste()
    #safe word to stop program, copy this word to break while and stop program
    if current_cb == 'STOP!':
        print ("STOPPED.")
        break
    # if the current content doesn't match the old content stored in cb
    if current_cb != cb:
        # and if the link includes "https://pastebin.com/" and is 29 characters long
        if "https://pastebin.com/" in current_cb and len(current_cb) == 29:
            # set the raw url to the clipboard content while replacing url with raw url
            raw_url = current_cb.replace("https://pastebin.com/", "https://pastebin.com/raw/")
            # copy raw URL to the clipboard
            pyperclip.copy(raw_url)
            # paste the current content of the clipboard for testing
            paste = pyperclip.paste()
            print ("RAW URL: " + str(paste))
            # set the old clipboard content = the current clipboard conten
            cb = current_cb
            #sleep for a second
            sleep(1)
```

Try this. Explanation in code comment.

My understanding of the requirements of your project:

1. Check to see if there is a Pastebin link in the clipboard.
2. Get the text content of the link.
3. Copy the content to clipboard.

If this is not correct, please let us know.

```
import requests
import pyperclip
from time import sleep

# get the content of clipboard
cb=pyperclip.paste()

while True:
    # get the content of clipboard while True
    current_cb = pyperclip.paste()
    #safe word to stop program, copy this word to break while and stop program
    if current_cb == 'STOP!':
        print ("STOPPED.")
        break
    # if the current content doesn't match the old content stored in cb
    if current_cb != cb:
        # and if the link includes "https://pastebin.com/raw/"
        if "https://pastebin.com/raw/" in current_cb:
            # set the url to the clipboard content
            url = current_cb
            # request the url
            r = requests.get(url)
            # store the response in content
            content = r.text
            # copy the contents of content to the clipboard
            pyperclip.copy(content)
            # paste the current content of the clipboard for testing
            paste = pyperclip.paste()
            print ("CURRENT CONTENT IN CLIPBOARD: " + str(paste))
            # set the old clipboard content = the current clipboard conten
            cb = current_cb
            #sleep for a second
            sleep(1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, i'm just trying to receive the "/raw/linkhere/ text from inside of the link and then copy that to my clipboard. The link just stays the same even when copied.

Comment: @tjm111245 So you'd like Python to change the link to the raw text link when you copy a link from Pastebin?